# Desabilitar 'disabled' de um botão com nível de acesso

Tags: html, typescript

Tenho uma lista de itens, onde é possível editar e excluir eles através de um botão, e temos níveis de acesso nesse sistema, possuindo 'Vendedores' e 'Usuários Master', mas os vendedores não podem excluir nada, apenas os Masters, portanto, no botão de excluir, eu coloquei um 'disabled' portanto, ele fica desabilitado, e quero fazer uma verificação para quando for Usuário Master, tirar esse disabled, permitindo a exclusão, tentei um utilizar um removeAttribute, mas retorna esse erro:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
        Tem certeza que deseja excluir o Ramo ?
     </h5>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
        Não
     </button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="del()" disabled id="delete">
        Sim
     </button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  disableDelete() {
    let username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
    console.log('Username: ', username);


    if(username === 'Arthur' || username == 'admin') {
      let btnRemove = document.getElementById('delete').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Está utilizando **Angular**?

Comment: Sim, mas um dos mais atuais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando **Angular** logo não precisa de função nenhuma para fazer o quer, no **TS** é só verificar qual o tipo do usuário no **`ngOnInit()`** e guardar o valor em uma propriedade da classe do componente e no **Html** no botão fazer o **property binding** com a propriedade:

#### HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
    Tem certeza que deseja excluir o Ramo ?
 </h5>
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
 </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
    Não
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="del()" 
    [disabled]="verifica" id="delete">Sim
 </button>
</div>
```

#### TS

```
export class SeuComponent implements OnInit {
  verifica: boolean;
  tipoUser = 'Admin';   // pega o que vem do storage

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.tipoUser == 'Qualquer coisa' || this.tipoUser == 'Admin') this.verifica = false;
    else this.verifica = true;
  }
}
```

> Para saber mais sobre property binding em Angular veja [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).
>
> Para ver um exemplo funcionando veja [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-binding).

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessário atribuir a ação a uma variável. Teste da maneira abaixo.

```js
if(username === 'Arthur' || username == 'admin') {
  document.getElementById('delete').disabled = false;
}
```

Para desabilitar o botão, basta mudar para true.

Comment: Concordo, realmente não é necessário a variável, mas o .disable não é entendível, pelo menos não no typescript eu acho, retorna isso:

Property 'disable' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: Na verdade, esse erro é corrigido se eu colocar isso:
(<HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById('delete')).disabled = true;... Porém, retorna o mesmo erro, que a pergunta acima: TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null